# $z$ is a root of $F$ iff $\bar z$ is root of $F$

Tags: polynomials

$F(x) \in R$ and $z \in C$.
I need to prove that z is a root of $F$ iff  $\bar z$ is root of $F$

I can't think of a way to prove that... will love some guidance.

Comment: I guess you mean, the *coefficients* of the polynomial $F$ are real, i.e. $F\in\Bbb R[x]$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say, $F(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+...$ where all these $c_i$ are real.

Then try to show that $\overline{F(z)}=F(\bar z)$ by using the nice properties of complex conjugation with respect to $+,-,\cdot$ operations of $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to remember that $\overline{zw}=\bar z \bar w$ and  $\overline{z+w}=\bar z + \bar w$, for any complex numbers. Also, for real numbers, its conjugate is the same.

Comment: still dont see how it helps me.. and I guess it so easy but...

Comment: $\overline{a_nz^n}=\overline{a_n}\overline{z^n}=a_n\overline{z}^n$. Take the sum and use the fact that $\sum a_iz^i=0$ and $\bar 0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

$z$ is a root of F iff $F(z)=0$
iff $\overline{F(z)}=\overline{0}$ iff $F(\overline{z})=0$ iff $\overline{z}$ is a root of $F$.

All you need to show is $\overline{F(z)}=F(\overline{z})$. This is pretty easy to show.:)